# vs2013 azure web deploy fails with Unknown ProviderOption:DefiningProjectFullPath

Tags: asp.net, azure, visual-studio-2013, webdeploy

I've been working with vs 2013 and Azure for a while now, but all of a sudden, today I can no longer deploy a project to one of my web roles.

This is the message that is in the logs:

`Transformed Web.config using C:\Users\{redacted}\Web.Release.config into obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
Auto ConnectionString Transformed Areas\HelpPage\Views\Web.config into obj\Release\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Areas\HelpPage\Views\Web.config.
Auto ConnectionString Transformed Views\Web.config into obj\Release\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Views\Web.config.
Auto ConnectionString Transformed obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config into obj\Release\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Web.config.
Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp.
Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to https://waws-prod-am2-003.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net/msdeploy.axd?site={redacted} ...
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4253,5): Error : Web deployment task failed. (Unknown ProviderOption:DefiningProjectFullPath. Known ProviderOptions are:skipInvalid.)
Publish failed to deploy.`

I haven't found anything relevant on the internet about `Unknown ProviderOption:DefiningProjectFullPath`, aside from 2 ananswered questions here that had nothing to do with Azure.

Any ideas what this might be from or how to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: have you tried again after restarting your computer? Sometimes it would take me more than 3 tries before I get a success publish

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by switching to the ftp publishing profile (azure also exports that).
It's much slower but it works.
Still have no clue why the web publish doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem when on VS 2013.4 trying to build a Web Deploy ZIP package (not using Azure). I had switched from using the standard targets to MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets 12.0.1 (from NuGet).

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\packages\MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets.12.0.1\tools\VSToolsPath\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
```

Switching back to the standard allowed the zip package to build without error.

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
```

Since the error was the same, the solution may be.